# XCode calling a function before it's called?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary

I've got a bizarre question that I've been researching/playing with for hours now.

I'm working on a simple note-taking app, storing notes in an `NSMutableDictionary` with the Key as the title and the Value as the note.  I've got a delegate function that saves the contents of an `NSTextView` each time it changes.

```
-(void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString *currentNote = [_mainTextField string];
    [Data setNote:currentNote forKey:currentKey];
}
```

and then adds it to the Dictionary.

```
+(void)setNote:(NSString *)note forKey:(NSString *)key {
    [allNotes setObject:note forKey:key];
}
```

while `currentKey` is a global variable that is updated elsewhere (and which I have tested thoroughly and is working fine).

**Here's where it gets weird:** You'd expect the Dictionary to update a single Key for each call of `setNote:forKey:` as long as the Keys are all unique (which they are).  But instead, it's updating *all previously-updated Keys each time.*  So if you had a Dictionary like this.

```
"John" = "apples";
"David" = "apples";
```

and you updated "John" to "bananas"

```
"John" = "bananas";
"David" = "apples";
```

and then you updated "David" to "oranges", you'd get this:

```
"John" = "oranges";
"David" = "oranges";
```

I've breakpoint'd and NSLog'd the hell out of it, and what I've discovered is that "John" changes to "oranges" by the beginning of the `setNote:forKey:` method, **before the `[allNotes setObject:note forKey:key]` line is even called.**  Now, that's the only place in my entire program that changes the `allNotes` Dictionary, but somehow the original row is being re-changed before the function is even called.  The first time you make a change (the "bananas" round) everything works perfectly regardless of the size of the Dictionary or which entry is being changed, and the second time (the "oranges" round) it all works perfectly again, except for changing the previously-changed rows as well.

I don't know how to get any more exact with the cause in my code, since the exact instant a key is pressed, `textDidChange:` gets called and by that point the first entry has already been altered.  And notably, when I stop the app and re-run, it goes back to changing the first one normally, and begins the whole thing again.

The other weird part is, the Key variables are working fine.  I've checked in the debugger: both the global variable `currentKey` and the local variable `key` derived from it will be "David", and yet the changes will affect both "David" and "John", and any others changed before "John" as well.  How could it even know what lines were previously edited, with only the current Key value to work with?

I am admittedly a Cocoa beginner, but I am absolutely stumped.  Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a key/value pair is added to a dictionary the key is *copied* while the value is *retained*. Keys are copied so they cannot be changed - the internal organisation of the dictionary is based on the keys.

The values are retained as they must continue to exist while in the dictionary, but if the value is a mutable type then it is OK for it to be mutated. E.g. If you create a dictionary of `NSTextField` objects then the association between keys and `NSTextField` objects is fixed, but the *contents* of the individual text fields themselves can change.

It looks like that in your code `[_mainTextField string]` is returning a reference to the *same* `NSMutableString` object each time it is called. This would mean that every value in your dictionary is a reference to the same mutable object and give you the behaviour you are seeing. You can address this by either changing `[_mainTextField string]` to return an `NSString` by *copying* the mutable string it is using internally; or by copying what is returned using `[[_mainTextField string] copy]`. The former is better if the purpose of `[_mainTextField string]` is to return a snapshot of the current value of `_mainTextField` (whatever its type is - the sample does not say).

Comment: You are awesome!  The `[[_mainTextField string] copy]` seems to be working.  Since you said the other way was better, though, can you share a code snippet for how the former might be done?  This whole "copying it internally" concept is new to me.  I'm trying to return a regular `NSString` with the current contents of `_mainTextField`, which is an `NSTextView` inside an `NSScrollView.`

Comment: If `_mainTextField` is an instance of `NSTextView` then you cannot "copy it internally" as you are not the class author. `NSTextView` inherits its `string` method from its superclass `NSText`, and the description of the method states "For performance reasons, this method returns the current backing store of the text object. If you want to maintain a snapshot of this as you manipulate the text storage, you should make a copy of the appropriate substring." - hence the need for the `copy`. If `_mainTextField` is an instance of your own class that incorporate the `copy` into its `string` method.

Comment: And understanding begins to dawn...  Thank you again!